# Incorrect conversion of list into dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to convert a list into dataframe using python.
I have all the necessary data in my list(correct data), in the form of list of dictonaries. See list of dictonaries below:

```
 [{'ABC': 'abc1', 'DEF': 'def1', 'GHI': 'ghi1', 'JKL': 'jkl1', 'MNO': 'mno1', 'PQR': 'pqr1', 'STU': 'stu1', 'VWX': 'vwx1', 'YZ': 'yz1'},
 {'ABC': 'abc2', 'DEF': 'def2', 'GHI': 'ghi2', 'JKL': 'jkl2', 'MNO': 'mno2', 'PQR': 'pqr2', 'STU': 'stu2', 'VWX': 'vwx2', 'YZ': 'yz2'},......
```

I am using the following command to convert it to a dataframe.

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(case_list_new)
```

Instead of taking the dictionary keys as column headers, the dataframe is taking the numbers 0-8 as column headers, and printing the column names in a loop where the dictionary values should be. This is the dataframe output I get :

```
     0   1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8  
0   ABC DEF  GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ
1   ABC DEF  GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWX YZ
```

What could be the reason for this output and how may I put it right ?
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: This should have worked. Trying `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')` works for me?

Comment: Hi @coldspeed, tried that, still the same output :(

Comment: Then your actual data has something that you have not shown here. Please provide a [mcve] and make sure the data reproduces your problem.

Comment: @learner, can you try just use `DataFrame` constructor ?

Comment: That worked for me and Mr.@Nihal. Please share your source code.

Comment: I had tried using just the Dataframe constructor first, that didn't work however.

Comment: @coldspeed ok the dataframe constructor worked, don't know what problem was occuring earlier.
Sorry for troubling you all and thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = [{'ABC': 'abc1', 'DEF': 'def1', 'GHI': 'ghi1', 'JKL': 'jkl1', 'MNO': 'mno1', 'PQR': 'pqr1', 'STU': 'stu1',
   'VWX': 'vwx1', 'YZ': 'yz1'},
  {'ABC': 'abc2', 'DEF': 'def2', 'GHI': 'ghi2', 'JKL': 'jkl2', 'MNO': 'mno2', 'PQR': 'pqr2', 'STU': 'stu2',
   'VWX': 'vwx2', 'YZ': 'yz2'}]

newdf1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
newdf2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
print(newdf1)
print(newdf2)
```

output:

```
    ABC   DEF   GHI   JKL   MNO   PQR   STU   VWX   YZ
0  abc1  def1  ghi1  jkl1  mno1  pqr1  stu1  vwx1  yz1
1  abc2  def2  ghi2  jkl2  mno2  pqr2  stu2  vwx2  yz2

    ABC   DEF   GHI   JKL   MNO   PQR   STU   VWX   YZ
0  abc1  def1  ghi1  jkl1  mno1  pqr1  stu1  vwx1  yz1
1  abc2  def2  ghi2  jkl2  mno2  pqr2  stu2  vwx2  yz2
```